# How to do `abi.encodeWithSignature` in Python and eth-brownie

Tags: solidity, web3.py, python, brownie

I want to encode data using `abi.encodeWithSignature` in Python, and send the output from this into a contract function parameter. Now the problem is I can't figure out how should I do it.

The function I want to encode is like `abi.encodeWithSignature("Increment(uint256)",55)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find teh equivalent bytes of `abi.encodeWithSignature` in Python and eth-brownie by using `encode_input`.

In the above example I had to find the encoding of `Increment()` and with `uint256` parameter value of `55`. Suppose the contract is deployed in test and stored in variable `ContractA`.

To find `abi.encodeWithSignature` I will write:

```
value = ContractA.Increment.encode_input(55)
```

Somehow it took me alot of time to find this, therefore I am writing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

- I think there is some padding problem if we just do this `ContractA.Increment.encode_input(55)`.
- This is the correct way to add padding. Say there is `contract` which has a function `methodName`.

```py
value = Contract.methodName.encode_input()
print(value)
# wrong
>> '0xa7a7e4e8' 
value = Contract.methodName.encode_input()
# add padding to make it 32 bytes
value = value + "0" * (66 - len(value))
print(value)
# correct
>> '0xa7a7e4e800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
```